# Using OWL API, how to get class or individual name

Tags: semantic-web, owl, owl-api

I can get OWLClass and access the information. The classes and individuals are along with prefix.
Is there any method to get rid of prefix?
For example:

```
OWLClass cls = factory.getOWLClass(":Person", pm);
for (OWLIndividual indiv : cls.getIndividuals(onto)) {
    System.out.println(indiv.toString());
}
```

print:
`<http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/ont.owl#Mon>`
`<http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/ont.owl#Dad>`

What I want is just `Mon` `Dad`

**UPDATE:**
Thank you Ignazio.
I found that the key is `getIRI()` method.

```
for (OWLIndividual indiv : owlclass.getIndividuals(onto)) {
    System.out.println(indiv.asOWLNamedIndividual().getIRI().getFragment());
}

for (OWLClassExpression expre : owlclass.getSubClasses(onto)) {
    System.out.println(expre.asOWLClass().getIRI().getFragment());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For entities, you can do this with OWLEntity.getIRI().getFragment().

Note however that not all entities have a name of this kind, as an Iri can legitimately end with / or #

Answer (score 4):

A little update : getFragment() is deprecated now. I use getShortForm() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and used `OWLEntity.getIRI().getShortForm()`.

Answer (score 0):

I retrieved class names into a List as follows
get ontology from the disk and assign to variable o Type ; 
OWLOntology o;
And Created list to add Classes as follows
List listofClass = new ArrayList();
Then add the following codes

```
    Collection<OWLClass> classes = o.getClassesInSignature();

//getting class names in the ontology
    for (OWLClass owlClass : classes) {
            System.out.println(owlClass.getIRI().getShortForm());
            listofClass.add(owlClass.getIRI().getShortForm());
      }
        return listofClass;
    }
```